# Word Suggestions not working after ICS on AT&T Galaxy S 2

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, swype, auto-correct

I recently updated to ICS on my AT&T Galaxy S 2 but since then the word suggestions has been working intermittently even though it is turned on while using Swype keyboard. Is anyone else facing this problem?

Comment: My wife's AT&T-branded SGS2 (running CM9 nightly builds) is having the same issue with Swype's suggestions disappearing from time to time.  She has to go into Swype settings and toggle that setting off and back on again to get it back.  Strange, but I have not had this happen on my Galaxy Nexus (also running CM9 nightly builds.)